# Can't SSH or FTP into the server with new user accounts?

Tags: server, ssh, ftp

I have a mediatemple web server configured with Nginx. At first, i created one user account and used that user to log into to the server through SSH... it worked perfectly and still i can use that user account to login to the server.

But, when i create a new user account now, that account can't connect to the server! When i try to connect with SSH, after i give the user name and password the connection gets closed automatically!

When i try to FTP into the site through Filezilla (using that user account) it says :

```
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: What is the new user shell? What do your log files say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What shell is set for this new user?

Try following command: (don't paste the output)

less /etc/passwd

Example output:
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
user:x:1:1:user:/home/user:/bin/sh

The last entry is the login shell which is used. If this entry differs from the one user which is working - change it. Please make a copy of this file before changing it!

Another reason could be that the ftp client is using the passive type of communication. With passive mode the client is opening additional ports for the data communication.
So try to deactivate the passive mode in the ftp client.

The log of the ftp client should inherit following line if it using passive mode:
[R] 227 Entering Passive Mode (81,255,103,144,122,177)